# $.Deferred().promise vs $.get().promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am trying the following code:

```
var x=$.get();
x.promise();

var y=new $.Deferred();
y.promise();
```

as to make the comparison between `$.Deferred().promise and $.get().promise`. **In both cases** ( x.promise() and y.promise() ), Chrome debugger drives me to the **same** line of jQuery source code:

```
promise: function( obj ) {
    return obj != null ? jQuery.extend( obj, promise ) : promise;
}
```

However, `x.promise==y.promise` returns **false!!!** Why? I cannot give an explanation...

I need some help. Thank you

Comment: because it's a different promise, a different object  ...  or, `({}) != ({})`

Comment: Two promise objects and in js two objects are not equal.

Comment: I am not comparing the promise objects, but the function objects themselves. Why not to refer to the same memory spot where the function object of method .promise lies?

Comment: The same reason that `$('#foo').show` and `$('#bar').show` both use the same function. They are different objects but they use the same jQuery prototype.

Comment: @Barmar in your example $('#foo').show==$('#bar').show. That's what I expected and for x.promise,y.promise...

Comment: Oops, I misread the question.

Comment: The simple explanation is that they are different closures of the same function. They're not equal because they're closed over different variable values.

Comment: @Barmar do you agree with Jelly's answer, below?

Comment: I think it's right, but he doesn't explain it very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ILIAS
That is because is not the same instance about the object `defer` and object `promise`, even they create from same code...
Every time you call `jQuery.Deferred` method will create the new object.

```
Deferred: function( func ) {
    // notice, these define is in the Deferred method, every time is whole new object
    var tuples = [
            // action, add listener, listener list, final state
            [ "resolve", "done", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "resolved" ],
            [ "reject", "fail", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "rejected" ],
            [ "notify", "progress", jQuery.Callbacks("memory") ]
        ],
        state = "pending",
        promise = {
            state: function() {
                return state;
            },
            always: function() {
                deferred.done( arguments ).fail( arguments );
                return this;
            },
            then: function( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
                var fns = arguments;
                return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
                    jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
                        var action = tuple[ 0 ],
                            fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
                        // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
                        deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
                            var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
                            if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
                                returned.promise()
                                    .done( newDefer.resolve )
                                    .fail( newDefer.reject )
                                    .progress( newDefer.notify );
                            } else {
                                newDefer[ action + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    fns = null;
                }).promise();
            },
            // Get a promise for this deferred
            // If obj is provided, the promise aspect is added to the object
            promise: function( obj ) {
                return obj != null ? jQuery.extend( obj, promise ) : promise;
            }
        },
        deferred = {};
```

Comment: Please notice `get` method is get `defer` object from the `Deferred` method too.